# SweetAlert - Mvc - @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert2

//GET Request How can I get it after Sweetalert approval. I stop with  preventDefault(); , but what can I do to continue the process.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(" ", "OdemeSil", new { id = Security.Encrypt(item.İd.ToString()) },
                               new AjaxOptions()
                               {
                                   HttpMethod = "GET",
                                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,

                               }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs fa fa-trash-o", @title = "Sil", @id = "confirm-dialog"})


<script>
    $(document).on('click', '#confirm-dialog', function (e) {

 e.preventDefault();   
        swal({
            title: 'Silmek İstediğine Eminmisin?',
            text: "Bu İşlem Geri Alınamaz..!!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Evet',
            cancelButtonText: 'Hayır'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                swal(
                    'Silindi',
                    'Kayıt Başarı İle Silindi.',
                    'success'
                )
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```